# How to merge rows in a dataframe based on a column value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have a data-set that is in the shape of this, where each row represents a in a specific match that is specified by the `gameID`.

```
  gameID          Won/Lost   Home   Away  metric2 metric3 metric4   team1 team2 team3 team4
2017020001         1          1      0      10      10      10      1     0     0      0
2017020001         0          0      1      10      10      10      0     1     0      0
```

The thing I want to do is create a function that takes the rows with the same `gameID` and joins them. As you can see in data example below, the two rows represents one game that is split up into a home team (row_1 ) and an away team (row_2). I want these two rows to sit on one row only.

```
Won/Lost  h_metric2 h_metric3 h_metric4 a_metric2 a_metric3 a_metric4 h_team1 h_team2 h_team3 h_team4 a_team1 a_team2 a_team3 a_team4
1            10       10         10        10         10        10      1       0        0      0         0      1        0      0
```

How do I get this result?

EDIT: I created too much confusion, posting my code so you can get a better grasp of the problem I want to solve.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

results = []
for game_id in range(2017020001, 2017020010, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/boxscore'.format(game_id)
r = requests.get(url)
game_data = r.json()

for homeaway in ['home','away']:

    game_dict = game_data.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats')
    game_dict['team'] = game_data.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    game_dict['homeaway'] = homeaway
    game_dict['game_id'] = game_id
    results.append(game_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)

df['Won/Lost'] = df.groupby('game_id')['goals'].apply(lambda g: (g == g.max()).map({True: 1, False: 0}))

df["faceOffWinPercentage"] = df["faceOffWinPercentage"].astype('float')
df["powerPlayPercentage"] = df["powerPlayPercentage"].astype('float')
df["team"] = df["team"].astype('category')
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['homeaway'])
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['team'])
```

Comment: What sense does the Won/Lost column make in the desired output?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, won/Lost column would be for home team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is under the assumption that you have exactly two rows per `gameID` and that you want to group by that ID. (It also assumes that I understand the question.)

**Improved solution**

Given a dataframe `df` such as

```
       gameID  Won/Lost  Home  Away  metric2  metric3  metric4  team1  team2  team3  team4
0  2017020001         1     1     0       10       10       10      1      0      0      0
1  2017020001         0     0     1       10       10       10      0      1      0      0
2  2017020002         1     1     0       10       10       10      1      0      0      0
3  2017020002         0     0     1       10       10       10      0      1      0      0
```

you can use `pd.merge` (and some data munging) like this:

```
>>> is_home = df['Home'] == 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> home = df[is_home].drop(['Home', 'Away'], axis=1).add_prefix('h_').rename(columns={'h_gameID':'gameID'})                                                                                                                                    
>>> away = df[~is_home].drop(['Won/Lost', 'Home', 'Away'], axis=1).add_prefix('a_').rename(columns={'a_gameID':'gameID'})                                                                                                                       
>>> pd.merge(home, away, on='gameID')                                                                                                                                                                                                           
       gameID  h_Won/Lost  h_metric2  h_metric3  h_metric4  h_team1  h_team2  h_team3  h_team4  a_metric2  a_metric3  a_metric4  a_team1  a_team2  a_team3  a_team4
0  2017020001           1         10         10         10        1        0        0        0         10         10         10        0        1        0        0
1  2017020002           1         10         10         10        1        0        0        0         10         10         10        0        1        0        0
```

(I kept the prefix for `Won/Lost` because it indicates that it's the statistic for the home team. Also, if anybody knows how to add the prefixes more elegantly without having to re-rename the `gameID` please leave a comment.)

---

**Original Attempt**

You can apply the following function after grouping

```
def munge(group): 
     is_home = group.Home == 1 
     wonlost = group.loc[is_home, 'Won/Lost'].reset_index(drop=True) 
     group = group.loc[:, 'metric2':] 
     home = group[is_home].add_prefix('h_').reset_index(drop=True) 
     away = group[~is_home].add_prefix('a_').reset_index(drop=True) 
     return pd.concat([wonlost, home, away], axis=1)
```

... like this:

```
>>> df.groupby('gameID').apply(munge).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)                                                                                                                                                                           
            Won/Lost  h_metric2  h_metric3  h_metric4  h_team1  h_team2  h_team3  h_team4  a_metric2  a_metric3  a_metric4  a_team1  a_team2  a_team3  a_team4
gameID                                                                                                                                                        
2017020001         1         10         10         10        1        0        0        0         10         10         10        0        1        0        0
2017020002         1         10         10         10        1        0        0        0         10         10         10        0        1        0        0
```

Comment: Well I can tell you that you understood it perfectly and executed even better, thank you really much for this, it was exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

i just suppose, you are working with bread and butter:
numpy, pandas & co?

if so, i furthermore assume, that your table currently is being stored in a pandas.DataFrame-instance called 'df':

Divide your df into two df's and then join them:

```
df_team1 = df[df['Won/Lost']==1]
df_team2 = df[df['Won/Lost']==0]
final_df = df_team1.join(df_team2, lsuffix='_team1', rsuffix='_team2', on='gameID')
```

You can, of course, edit it to better match your purposes. For instance create the df's based on Home/Away columns, etc.

BR
Ben
:]

Comment: Thank you for this Ben! It did what I asked for in the problem i asked for, all your assumptions were correct. I posted an EDIT with my code so you can get an even better understanding on how the data looks like.